# How to check the current state in evil mode?

Tags: evil

When writing elisp for evil mode, how can you check the currently active evil state?
(`normal`, `visual`, `insert`... etc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The state can be accessed via `evil-state`, eg:

```el
(cond
 ((eq evil-state 'visual) (do-something))
 ((eq evil-state 'normal) (do-other-thing))
 ((eq evil-state 'insert) (do-another-thing)))
```